# How to change logo when scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one issue that I cant resolve myselft, so I need your help. On [my site](http://deilbeatz.com/), I have integrated JQuery that change header background and color when scroll down, and works well. But issue is that I also want logo to change to black version when someone scroll down. I have tryed this JQ:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300)
{   
   jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});
   jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"black"}); 
   jQuery('.site_logo').css({"-webkit-filter":"invert(.8)"}); 
  jQuery('.site_logo').css({"filter":"invert(.8)"});
} else {
   jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"transparent"});
  jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"white"});
}
});
```

what invert white color to black, but red color invert to green, so its not as I expected. I have black version of logo, so I'm asking you, how to change black logo when someone scroll down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not removing filter after scrolling back to top.
Change your JS like

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300){   
    jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});
    jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"black"}); 
    jQuery('.site_logo').css({"-webkit-filter":"invert(.8)","filter":"invert(.8)"}); 
  } else {
    jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"transparent"});
    jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"white"});
    jQuery('.site_logo').css({"-webkit-filter":"none","filter":"none"});
  }
});
```

Also there is a better approach (for good look) of changing image on scroll, So you can achieve exactly the same design you want in logo after and before scroll like

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300){   
  jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});
  jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"black"}); 
  jQuery('.site_logo').attr('src','path/to/logo/after/scroll') 
  } else {
    jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"transparent"});
    jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"white"});
    jQuery('.site_logo').attr('src','path/to/logo/initially/')
 }
});
```

Comment: This works, but red color invert to green. Check my site (listed in first post), and will see for what i talking about.

Comment: Your second modified JQ make the job. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how do you access the src attribute?

```
$('.site_logo').attr('src', 'BLACKLOGO.png');

jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300)
    {   
       jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"white"});
       jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"black"}); 
      jQuery('.site_logo').attr('src', 'http://deilbeatz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/DeilBeatzwhite.png');
    } else {
       jQuery('#navigation').css({"background":"transparent"});
      jQuery('.menu-item').css({"color":"white"});
      jQuery('.site_logo').attr('src', 'http://deilbeatz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Deil-Beatz-‌​menu-logo-black.png');
    }
});
```

Hope that helps, if not let me know what you need and I'll try to help

Comment: So just put that in the if and else states with the white and black logos

Comment: I inserted this row in JQ:

`jQuery('.site_logo').attr('src', 'http://deilbeatz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Deil-Beatz-menu-logo-black.png');`

But this update also my main logo in black header.. So how to use this black logo, ONLY in white background ?

Comment: Only put that in the ELSE bit and put the $('.site_logo').attr('src', 'http://deilbeatz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/DeilBeatzwhite.png'); in the first part of the IF where you do the black related style

Comment: I've updated my code example if its correct please accept